# IE Search text function doesn't work with codes generated from AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, internet-explorer, find

I have developed a page to call an AJAX function and construct an HTML table (e.g. ....) with populated data. When the page is loaded in IE, the "Find" function doesn't work. By clicking "View Source", it only shows . And when I click F12, I'm able to see the HTML table. The issue doesn't happen in Chrome. How should I use load the data returned from AJAX call to make it work in IE?

Comment: can you pls share the code?

Comment: Can you post enough code or create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we could reproduce the problem and narrow down the problem. Besides, please check the following samples, they all work well in IE browser: [Link 1](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/631790/Search-and-Filter-Dynamic-HTML-table-as-you-type-in-TextBox-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet/) and [Link 2](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)